# detecting singular objects using mobilenet & (dnn) opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv

The problem is simply choosing a single object out of a list of objects for a model, and detecting only that using opencv-python.

this was an old question, I fully agree that I did not do any sort of proper research before asking this question, I can assure you that this won't happen again and that I am very sorry for my negligence.

the files:

```
https://github.com/sidpro-hash/Object-Detection
    -only download:
     -"coco.names"
     -"frozen_inference_graph.pb"
     -"ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
```

here is the code:

```
    import cv2
import cvzone
thres = 0.5 #to detect objects

#img = cv2.imread('cat3.jpg')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weigthsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weigthsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=0.5)
    print(classIds, bbox)

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            #cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0,0,255), thickness=3)
            cvzone.cornerRect(img, box)
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId-1].upper(), (box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,0,0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, str(round(confidence*100, 2)), (box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,0,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("output", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

edit: this is a very old question, and seeing that stackoverflow is preventing me from asking questions today, I have to edit the old ones. I also edited the question so it is better to understand and up-to-date

the answer is simple, just filter out the list of objects and display/detect only one:

```
def find_obj(img, draw=True, objects=[]):
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=0.5)
    #print(classIds, bbox)=
    if len(objects) == 0: objects = classNames
```

the function stays the same, except you add an argument and a little handler. the argument is a list of objects to detect and by adding a little handler at the start of the function you can make the objects argument optional. you then only feed those object names to detect into the model.

again, I am very sorry. It has been 2 years since I had gotten into programming, I'm a 13 year old male that loves coding. I'm sorry for my past self and I understand stack Exchange's suspicion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, you can use a simple logical operation to check class ID then display only bounding boxes belonging to that class (If you don't want to retrain the model with single output layer)

However, to correctly answer the question and use the best practical scenario; let's check what's the difference between single class and multiclass object detection is and if it is worth to retrain it.

In terms of model architecture, only different layer is the fully connected layer (Of course only if you're using the same backbone for feature extraction.) Single-class object detectors only have a regression layer set, whereas multi-class object detection models have regression layer + softmax classifier to detect and classify multi class labels.

So which one you should use?

In some cases (even if you're trying to detect single class) where different objects look very similar to eachother, seperating them into multiple classes and training them in multi-class detector will reduce the chances to give false positive result for the class you want to desire. You may think this case like you do not now what cat is and since they're similar to dogs, you can easily mistake a cat to a dog. But if you now what cat and dog are seperately, the chances are low to mistake them for eachother.

Almost all the time, there is no general solution to a deep learning problem. But nowing the theory behind them will lead you to success.

If you want to convert that model (ssd_mobilenet_v3) to single-class object detector, all you need to do is [remove fully connected layer, add your own then train as usual](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/12/multi-class-object-detection-and-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/);

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# 1 for single-class detection
NUMBER_OF_CLASSES = 1

# Include_top False means you exclude FC (Fully Connected) Layers of the model
model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(150, 150, 3))

# This freezes all layers of the MobileNet to not update it during training process
model.trainable = False

# We flatten the output layer so we can add our own (With 1 class)
flatten = model.output
flatten = Flatten()(flatten)

# construct a fully-connected layer header to output the predicted
# bounding box coordinates
bboxHead = Dense(128, activation="relu")(flatten)
bboxHead = Dense(64, activation="relu")(bboxHead)
bboxHead = Dense(32, activation="relu")(bboxHead)
bboxHead = Dense(4, activation="sigmoid",
                 name="bounding_box")(bboxHead)

# construct a second fully-connected layer head, this one to predict
# the class label
softmaxHead = Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
softmaxHead = Dropout(0.5)(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dense(512, activation="relu")(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dropout(0.5)(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dense(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, activation="softmax",
                    name="class_label")(softmaxHead)

model = Model(
    inputs=model.input,
    outputs=(bboxHead, softmaxHead)
)

## Training........
```

Comment: hey @Ege Yıldırım , what type of tensorflow? i am using pycharm so i tried installing the libraries; but it still gave me an error saying that it didnt find keras in the tensorflow files..

Comment: @Keshav.h try tensorflow.python.keras :) I Appreciate your work at that age, Here is a huge hint for your future work = learn how to use google efficiently! Good luck!

Comment: hello again @Ege Yıldırım . I took your advice and I can properly solve my code problems using extensive research. I thank you for answering this question as it has helped me to get a lot better and realize to use my head and my best friend more ("google" == "best friend") cheers.